# webrtc with firebase :how to fix black screen on ios/safari

Tags: javascript, firebase, safari, html5-video, webrtc

I work on video calling in my web app. I tried [https://github.com/webrtc/FirebaseRTC/tree/solution][1]
example which on https://webrtc.org/getting-started/firebase-rtc-codelab here.

It works in these browsers:

- desktop/chrome----->desktop/chrome
- desktop/chrome----->desktop/firefox
- desktop/firefox----->desktop/firefox

but not Safari I can see just a black screen. It doesn't work.

- desktop/chrome---->ios/safari
- ios/safari---->ios/safari

actually I see black screen but I think safari get mediastream but cant show.

I have this code in codelab:

```
 peerConnection.addEventListener('track', event => {//other pc track
      console.log('Got remote track:', event.streams[0]);
       event.streams[0].getTracks().forEach(track => {
        console.log('Add a track to the remoteStream:', track);
        remoteStream.addTrack(track);
      });
    });
```

How can I fix this problem?

Comment: This question has merit since it touches on a tricky area and unearthed a bug in Safari. I vote to reopen. See https://github.com/webrtc/FirebaseRTC/issues/1

Answer (score 6):

I solved problem it work on safari I can get videStream now.
I changed this code in codelab

```
 peerConnection.addEventListener('track', event => {//other pc track
      console.log('Got remote track:', event.streams[0]);
       event.streams[0].getTracks().forEach(track => {
        console.log('Add a track to the remoteStream:', track);
        remoteStream.addTrack(track);
      });
    });
```

to

```
peerConnection.addEventListener('track', event => {//other pc track
      console.log('Got remote track:', event.streams[0]);

        document.querySelector('#remoteVideo').srcObject = event.streams[0];
        console.log(event.streams[0]);
        remoteStream = event.streams[0];


    });
```

I think safari don't support **remoteStream.addTrack(track**);(*remoteStream is a MediaStream obj*) I searched about this issue can t find anything.

Comment: addTrack is working for me on iOs 13 but only on second try, first one gives me a black stream, for now i'll be using event.stream

Answer (score 3):

Adding **playsinline** like so:

```
<video playsinline autoplay></video>
```

Helped in my case

Answer (score 1):

I have found that adding the `playsinline` HTML attribute does not work.

You can try enabling the `playsInline` option using JavaScript instead :

```js
document.querySelector('video#remoteVideo').playsInline = true;
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe the problem is that the video object is not "updated" on addTrack. I solved this by setting the srcObject every time I add tracks:

```
peerConnection.addEventListener('track', event => {
    event.streams[0].getTracks().forEach(track => {
        remoteStream.addTrack(track);
    });
    myRemoteVideo.srcObject = remoteStream;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You must add `playisinline` attribute using JS, however:

```js
video.playsinline = true; // ❌ This does not work on iOS (although works everywhere else)

video.setAttribute('playsinline', ''); // ✅ This works on iOS and everywhere else
```